# Python function multiple IF statements?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have question regarding for loops and functions, so there list of values which as three input variables which are values for example 0-5 or direction (West, North etc), I am not sure if I using If statement correctly. Have I done something wrong with for loop command or the function?

Example of array input variables but there isn't any set limit in data set:

```
['Start', 'Bottom right', 1]['South', 1, 1], ['North', 3, 4], ['West', 4, 0], ['West', 2, 0], ['South', 3, 4]
```

If I run the function, it will always give me else function and won't follow any of commands.

[image]

```
def follow_path(a):
    legend()    #draw legend

    for draw in a:
        direction(a[0])
        location(a[1])
        choosetoken(a[2])


def location(corner):
    if corner == 'Top left':
        goto(0,600)
    if corner == 'Top right':
        goto(600,600)
    if corner == 'Bottom left':
        home()
    if corner == 'Bottom right':
        goto(600,0)
    if corner == 'Center':
        goto(300,300)
    if corner == 1:
        forward(100)
    if corner == 2:
        forward(200)
    if corner == 3:
        forward(300)
    if corner == 4:
        forward(400)
    if corner == 5:
        forward(500)
    else:
        print ("Check input '1' is correct or not")

def direction(direction):
    if direction == 'West':
        setheading(180)
    if direction == 'East':
        setheading(0)
    if direction == 'North':
        setheading(90)
    if direction == 'West':
        setheading(270)
    if direction == 'Start':
        home()   
    else:
        print ("Check input '0' is correct or not")

def choosetoken(a): #Draw shapes
    if a == 0:
        youtube()
    elif a == 1:
        chrome()
    elif a == 2:
        googledrive()
    elif a == 3:
        gmail()
    elif a == 4:
        photo()
    else:
        print ("Token Value out of range, check if input '2' is correct or not")
```

Comment: You need `elif` not just `if`. Each `if` starts a completely new expression. Your current logic will check each `if`, if any of the `if` statements before the last one is `True` then is will also drop into the `else` clause of the last `if` statement because it will be `False`. Note: you are correctly using `elif` in the last function `choosetoken`. You may also want to investigate `dict`s to use as a dispatch mechanism vs. lots of `if` statements.

Comment: It would help if the else message printed the non-matching input value instead of just saying "does not match".

Comment: When you say; for draw in a: direction(a[0]) etc... what is a? is it a list? because you could be sending the same input into all the functions, draw number of times.

a[0] will be the first element in a, a[1] will be the second element in a; etc...

Comment: So maybe you should be writing for draw in a: functName(draw[0]) functName(draw[1]) functName(draw[2])

Comment: A is example list  like this `['Start', 'Bottom right', 1]['South', 1, 1], ['North', 3, 4], ['West', 4, 0], ['West', 2, 0], ['South', 3, 4]`

Comment: @AChampion, so replaced the if statement with dictionary, do I need clear dictionary command after each function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the order that if statements follow is:

```
if condition:
    doSomething()
elif anotherCondition:
    doSomethingDifferent()
elif anotherAnotherCondition:
    doSomethingDifferentAgain()
else:    #otherwise - if the above conditions don't satisfy(are not True)
    doThis()
```

Secondly;
The for loop has an issue where you are passing the list a into follow_path() then passing the first second and third elements of the list into direction, location and choosetoken.

```
def follow_path(a):
    for draw in a:
        direction(a[0])
        location(a[1])
        choosetoken(a[2])

def direction(thing):
    print("direction " + str(thing))

def location(thing):
    print("location " + str(thing))

def choosetoken(thing):
    print("choosetoken " + str(thing))

a = [['Start', 'Bottom right', 1],['South', 1, 1], ['North', 3, 4], ['West', 4, 0], ['West', 2, 0], ['South', 3, 4]]
follow_path(a)
```

Was this intended? or did you want something like this;

```
def follow_path(a):
    for draw in a:
        direction(draw[0])
        location(draw[1])
        choosetoken(draw[2])

def direction(thing):
    print("direction " + str(thing))

def location(thing):
    print("location " + str(thing))

def choosetoken(thing):
    print("choosetoken " + str(thing))

a = [['Start', 'Bottom right', 1],['South', 1, 1], ['North', 3, 4], ['West', 4, 0], ['West', 2, 0], ['South', 3, 4]]
follow_path(a)
```

What is happening is you are iterating through a list a; and selecting the zeroth, first and second item from each iteration.

So the first iteration would be ['Start', 'Bottom right', 1], I select the zeroth, first and second; 'Start', 'Bottom right', 1 respectively, then move to the next iteration which would be ['South', 1, 1], do the same thing and so on.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, both of the example are the same from what I can see?

Comment: Good answer. But using dict instead of lists would be more pythonic i guess.

Comment: The difference lies within the for loop, your indexing the iterations of the list, not the list as a whole.
instead of direction(a[0]), its direction(draw[0]) etc
I think mastering how iterations over lists and using if statements are more fundamental than using dictionary's. So when Bondspencil is ready they can try using dicts instead.

Comment: I got the  thing to work in end, but for by changing for loop to `draw[0]` and all if statements to elif.

Comment: Excellent, don't be afraid to break down the problem and use print to see what the functions are doing when accepting input and output. That was what I was trying to show you. If statements can get confusing when trying to find an issue, removing them and testing the function receives the right input is key to finding bugs. Remember short functions are better than long ones.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for the tip. Using Print helps alot of understanding what the output will be.